# Integral $ \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{\pi^{(x^{e})}\sin(x)\tan^{-1}(x)}{\sinh^{-1}\left({1+\cos(x)}\right)} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, hyperbolic-functions

I need help in evaluating the following integral :-

$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{\pi^{\displaystyle (x^{e})}\sin(x)\tan^{-1}(x)}{\sinh^{-1}\left({1+\cos(x)}\right)} dx$$

A brief solution would be very much appreciated.

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova 秀 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of you I would first check that the integrand is defined on $]0,\pi[$, and if so, that it is integrable. I Remember having long time ago such an exercise where the integrand wasn't even defined in the middle of the interval, to check if we were checking the basic stuff before trying to integrate. ;-)

Comment: @RobertGreen. Very nice comment ! To me the title is wrong : it is a mega-devil !!

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I will put as an answer, you're right ! ;-) En France, il n'y a qu'en prépa (et encore, à l'époque, maintenant je ne suis plus sûr qu'on poserait ça) qu'on pose ce genre de trucs. ;-)

Comment: $\pi^{x^e}$ looks pretty suspicious to me :)

Comment: Why do you say that? @vanna

Comment: Usually when you see constants like $\pi$ or $e$ in a homework (althought $e$ by itself is rare) it is for later simplification purposes. Here although trigonometry might generate some $\pi$ constants, there is no way $e$ is going to show up. $\pi$ and $e$ mixed up like that is odd and are indicative that the goal of the homework is not to compute the integral but show that the integrand is not integrable.

Comment: Which shows btw that the professor asking the question is not that smart. ;-) Or that he/she didn't want to ask a question that tricky. ;-)

Comment: @RobertGreen That comment is extremely rude. I happen to be a tenth grader who is in the process of learning the enigmas of math, and I've been very busy with approaching exams. I happened to have uploaded a wrong version (mix-up) of the intended question, probably due to being preoccupied.
I sincerely hope that as a mature person, you do not make such ignoble statements again to anyone,- that too without an iota of info regarding the person you are talking about. Do not become the quintessential jerk; people make mistakes in life. You've no right to judge a person's intellect passively.

Comment: Smart was about your professor ability of designing a really tricky exercise that appears not to be tricky, not about anything/anyone else. That's why I put smileys... That's why I also wrote "or", to tell that in fact the professor wasn't that into tricking you. So keep calm and do not fear anything about your intellect, it wasn't at all at stake here.

Comment: @RobertGreen I still want to genuinely thank you for pointing out the mistake in the initially incorrect question. (No sarcasm)

Are there problems in the rectified question? If so, tell me and I'll accordingly edit it, because I genuinely want to learn, and do not mind making mistakes! There's still a lot to learn for me, and I wholeheartedly admit mistakes I've made. And I'm sorry for popping at you in the previous comment. Just don't be so judgmental next time...

Comment: The first thing to learn and that I would put on your menu would be a small pinch of humor, which usually goes along with the ability of taking jokes. Bye.

Comment: I'm easily one of the most light-hearted with whom one can meet up with. I do take jokes casually, but with strangers that's not always the case for sometimes they do attack incessantly and unnecessarily. Hence I even replied again to say I'm sorry for having burst my bubble. So there's no issue between humour and me; I embrace it.

Comment: @RobertGreen Même en prépa on ne fait plus d'exos aussi fastidieux ;)

Comment: If you wish to comment something of importance, could you please do it in English? Google translate can only help so much...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the formula http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/math/7/2/a/72a1058ad2087aec467af24bddcf9479.png, we have $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\dfrac{\pi^{x^e}\sin x\tan^{-1}x}{\sinh^{-1}(1+\cos x)} dx=\dfrac{\pi}{2}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{m=1}^{2^n-1}\dfrac{(-1)^{m+1}\pi^\frac{m^e\pi^e}{2^{e(n+1)}}\sin\dfrac{m\pi}{2^{n+1}}\tan^{-1}\dfrac{m\pi}{2^{n+1}}}{2^n\sinh^{-1}\left(1+\cos\dfrac{m\pi}{2^{n+1}}\right)}$

Comment: Could you verify the formula in that link?

Comment: Could you verify the formula in that link?

Comment: could you please verify?

Answer (score 6):

Instead of you I would first check that the integrand is defined on ]0,π[, and if so, that it is integrable. You may have a surprise ! ;-)

I Remember having long time ago such an exercise where the integrand wasn't even defined in the middle of the interval, and the exercise was given to us only to check if we were checking the basic stuff before trying to calculate the integral.

Comment: Do you mean to say it isn't defined? If it isn't, then would you please mind explaining why it isn't?

Comment: For instance, imagine I ask you to calculate $\int_{0}^{\pi} \ln|cos x| dx$. You could answer : no way ! the function $x\mapsto \ln|cos x|$ is not even defined at the point $\frac{\pi}{2}\in [0,\pi]$, as the quantity $\ln(cos(\frac{\pi}{2})) = \ln(0)$ does not make sense.

Comment: No I understand the issue; I just wished to know where the problem was in the question.

Only now when I went through the post again I realized that the question I've posted is, in fact, completely incorrect! I've overlapped some trigonometric functions from another problem I was working on. I've actually interchanged cos^-1 x and tan x; I meant to write tan^-1 x and cos x...And the problem in my notebook doesn't even have a denominator for the argument of sinh^-1. I'll be careful next time I upload a question...