# Proof for a particular integration result.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series

$$I_1 =\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\dfrac{\pi^{x^e}\sin x\tan^{-1}x}{\sinh^{-1}(1+\cos x)} dx=\dfrac{\pi}{2}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{m=1}^{2^n-1}\dfrac{(-1)^{m+1}\pi^\frac{m^e\pi^e}{2^{e(n+1)}}\sin\dfrac{m\pi}{2^{n+1}}\tan^{-1}\dfrac{m\pi}{2^{n+1}}}{2^n\sinh^{-1}\left(1+\cos\dfrac{m\pi}{2^{n+1}}\right)}$$

---

I got this as an answer to a question I posted a while ago: [Integral $ \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{\pi^{(x^{e})}\sin(x)\tan^{-1}(x)}{\sinh^{-1}\left({1+\cos(x)}\right)} dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1160003/integral-int-0-pi-2-frac-pixe-sinx-tan-1x-sinh-1-l)

Is it true? *The answerer cited this formula*:  $$\int_a^bf(x){\rm d}x=(b-a)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{2^n-1}\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{2^n}f\left(a+\frac{m(b-a)}{2^n}\right)$$

*Question(s):*

1. **(a) Is the cited formula correct?**
2. **(b) Is the answer I got for $I_1$ correct?**
3. **(c) (If possible) If the answer to (a) and (b) are 'no' and 'no' or even 'yes' and 'no' respectively, what is the correct solution?**

---

*Note: Question has been edited to its current state (on March $10^{th}$); I just wanted to consolidate all the relevant information, so that a proper answer can be given.*

---

Comment: I will add that the above integral is contained in this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_integrals) (here is [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Lists_of_integrals&oldid=643918524) to the recent revision). See also [this discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20431338#20431338) in chat. The claim in the Wikipedia article is that this formula is valid for functions with bounded variation.

Comment: I have deleted my previous answer. I am still wondering how I made an obvious mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the nicer form is $$(b-a)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{2^n}\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{2^n}f\left(a+\frac{m(b-a)}{2^n}\right).$$

In this case the partial (outer most) sum up to $N$ is exactly $$\frac{(b-a)}{2^N}\sum_{m=1}^{2^N}f\left(a+\frac{m}{2^N}\right)$$ which is directly recognized as a Riemann sum.  In your case partial sums are Riemann sums from $a$ to $b-2^{-N}$ but in the limit this does not matter.

Comment: So the cited formula, as well as the evaluated anti-derivative are correct?

Comment: Sorry forgot to tag you while asking my query.

Comment: So what are you essentially trying to say? @WimC

Comment: @Kugelblitz That if a function $f$ is Riemann integrable then that formula holds. According to some references integrability is sufficient to ensure that the regular Riemann sums above converge to the integral.

Comment: Clear. So in my case, you've mentioned that it is a Riemann sum. So basically, you're saying that the answer I got to the integral I posed (i.e. $I_1$) is correct, right? @WimC

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Alright sir. If you're absolutely sure about the fact that the answer I've got (Which is in the first statement of my question) is correct, then I will definitely give the bounty; you've been immensely helpful. So I'm sorry to trouble you again, @WimC , but could you please confirm, that the answer I've got for the question I'd posed is correct, by saying yes again?

Comment: So you can you confirm whether you're sure or not? @WimC

Comment: Ok..I'm giving you the bounty.