# Trigonometry question.

Tags: trigonometry

$(1-\tan\theta)(1+\tan\theta)\sec^2\theta +  2^{\tan^2\theta} = 0 $

I have to find number of solutions of this equation such that $\frac{-\pi}{2}\lt\theta\lt\frac{\pi}{2}$.

I am not getting how to approach this question. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

I was able to reduce it to $2^{tan^2\theta} = \tan^4\theta-1 $ but I am not able to proceed further.

Comment: This is not *only* trigonometry: unless some slick trick is involved here (or, of course, unless something basic is being missed by me), this looks like a rather hard, very hard, trigonometric-exponential (a transcendental) equation. Are you sure of that $\;2^{\tan^2\theta}\;$ thing there?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. And it is not supposed to be extremely tough.. I'm still in high school so..

Comment: That must be one high school...or perhaps just a mistake of the teacher, or maybe you're supposed to do some graphing and evaluate approximately. Good luck!

Comment: @Timbuc It's simple trig for simplification, after that it looks like only approximation can be done... no way can a human manually compute the solutions for this answer with good precision.. I checked on WA myself..

Comment: @Kugelblitz Yes, the first trigonometric simplifications are pretty simple. The trigo-exponential outcome is awful, and it looks to me rather odd to put a high school student to deal with such ugly things, **unless** he was told to do some graphing and etc. (and even it isn't an easy graph if done without some program)

Comment: Exactly @Timbuc The OP says that he is preparing for IIT-JEE, which is a very difficult entrance test to get into the IITs (Best Indian colleges for Engineering).. So the 'high-school' part is not so much of a problem for one seriously studying to get into the college, but the weird part is that the solutions are too wonky, considering this exam tests extreme speed and accuracy..and no calculators are allowed. So I wholeheartedly agree with you about the crazy outcomes; usually the questions for these exams are very tough, but do not require computer help at all... So even I'm perplexed..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:$$(1-\tan\theta)(1+\tan\theta)\sec^2\theta +  2^{\tan^2\theta} = 0 $$
$$(1-\tan^2\theta)\sec^2\theta +  2^{\tan^2\theta} = 0 $$
$$(1-\tan^2\theta)(1+\tan^2\theta) +  2^{\tan^2\theta} = 0 $$
$$1-\tan^4\theta +  2^{\tan^2\theta} = 0 $$

---

(One more hint:
Let $\tan^2\theta = x$
Then equation is:
$$1-x^2+2^x=0$$
Solve for x, then solve for $\theta ).$

---

**Edit**: I checked the results on WA; Doesn't look like it's easily solvable by hand... So yes, graphing or a computational engine might be necessary... (Enter your equation here... it gives four plausible answers.. http://www.wolframalpha.com/widget/widgetPopup.jsp?p=v&id=bc455327d0772719486c1a3ecf2e96d3&title=Math%20Help%20Boards%3A%20Equation%20Solver&theme=blue)

Comment: I could reach until this point too. But then how do i proceed? Should I try graphing?

Comment: @ArpanBanerjee I made an edit.

Comment: Also @ArpanBanerjee were did you come across this? Which textbook? Also, are you in CBSE?

Comment: Yes, I am in CBSE. I am currently preparing for IIT-JEE and this question was in a book by the coaching institute I go to..

Comment: Both curves appear to be quite similar. How do I perform approximations?

Comment: Nice... I'm in tenth and am also preparing for IIT-JEE advanced.. But, I've not come across a question like this for IIT-JEE which yields a solution having such weird values... And the approximations maybe too time-consuming... there must be a simpler way... @ArpanBanerjee

Comment: Are you good with calculus? If so, could you please help me out with these two questions?: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1179598/proof-for-a-particular-integration-result ; http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1168651/analytic-form-of-int-frac-bigl-cos-1x-sqrt1-x2-bigr-1-ln-bi

Comment: I'm not nearly so good with calculus!

Comment: Alright, thank you for your time Arpan... Also, what is the solution according to your textbook?

Comment: They haven't provided a solution. But the answer is 2.

Comment: The answer cannot be $2$. When you look at $f(x)=1-x^2+2^x$, by inspection $x=3$ is a solution. So $\theta=\sqrt{\tan ^{-1}(3)}\approx 1.11761$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici 2 is the number of integral solutions and not the solution itself .

Comment: @ArpanBanerjee The answer provided by your textbook is correct . Your work was correct , then KugelBlitz's substitution was correct then Claude's inspection yielded 3 as x and hence $\theta$ has 2 values (+ and - $tan(\theta)$) . And all this is done without a graphic calculator and so it is an appropriate question .

Comment: @Klosew Actually, there exists another solution as well other than 3 (It's probably not obtainable by hand, but can be spotted by making a rough graph). The answer provided is wrong, it should be 4.

Comment: @ArpanBanerjee I dont think that a hand-sketched graph can be reliable in these close curves . Only 2 solutions exist between the specified range(as mentioned in the question) while 4 exist only if the range is all real numbers .

Comment: The range for $\tan \theta$ is all real numbers. And the curve was similar to the one for $x^2$ vs $2^x$. After $x=3 , x^2-1$ was higher so $2^x$ had to intersect it later. But you're right, it was quite close.

Comment: @ArpanBanerjee Yes . You are correct . Over [here](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%E2%88%92tan%5E4%CE%B8%2B2%5E%28tan%5E2%CE%B8%29%3D0&x=0&y=0) , I assumed that the close values were approximations and not the actual roots . In fact there are infinite real roots . I guess in your entrance exam , these would have been considered almost same values and then would have given 2 as the answer.